# Type refining an `any` type in flowtype

Tags: javascript, flowtype, nuclide-editor

I seem to be misunderstanding how flowtype refinements work (or maybe my Nuclide/Atom + Flow setup is being dumb). I'd like to do something like the following:

```
async function getIp(): Promise<string> {
  const resp = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/ip')
  const json = await resp.json() // `json: any` at this point
  if (typeof json.ip === 'string') {
    return json.ip
  } else {
    throw new Error("Weird response.")
  }
}
```

I'm fetching some JSON from an API endpoint, and it has type `any`. I'd like to sanity check that it has the right form (e.g. that it has a string `ip` field). Nuclide however warns me that every use of `json` in the above code is "Not covered by flow", including the entire `json.ip` expression. Why is that? I would have expected the `typeof` check to refine the type of `json.ip` to `string`.

Is there another way to refine untyped values?

Edit: Here's a [tryflow example](https://tryflow.org/?code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gc29tZUpzb24oKTogYW55IHsKICAgIHJldHVybiB7IGlwIDogInNvbWUgaXAiIH0KfQoKZnVuY3Rpb24gZ2V0SXAoKTogc3RyaW5nIHsKICAgIGNvbnN0IGpzb24gPSBzb21lSnNvbigpCiAgICBpZiAodHlwZW9mIGpzb24uaXAgPT09ICdzdHJpbmcnKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coanNvbi5pcCAqIDIpIC8vIHdoeSBpc24ndCB0aGlzIGFuIGVycm9yPwogICAgICAgIHJldHVybiBqc29uLmlwCiAgICB9IGVsc2UgewogICAgICAgIHRocm93IG5ldyBFcnJvcigiV2VpcmQuIikKICAgIH0KfQoKY29uc3QgcyA9ICJjYW4ndCBtdWx0aXBseSB0aGlzIGJ5IDIiCnMgKiAy) of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are seeing? If it is an `any` then the code would be fine even without the refinement.

Comment: Sure: Nuclide puts a yellow "uncovered by Flow" squiggle under `json`, `await resp.json()`, and `json.ip`, even inside the `return json.ip` branch of the conditional. As far as I can tell, Flow isn't refining `json.ip` to `string`; e.g. I can write `json.ip * 2` without getting a Flow error.

Comment: Ah, also, I believe I'm using version 0.37.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't refine `any`. You already can do anything with it, so what's the point?

If you want Flow to verify your code you should immediately convert your `any` to `mixed`:

```
const json: mixed = await resp.json()
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was missing--looks like I didn't read the flow docs carefully enough. Thanks very much!